# IF Statement firing error in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, triggers, declare

I'm executing this statement to create a trigger on a table using phpMyAdmin

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE NEW TRIGGER credit_refs AFTER UPDATE on investments FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE ref INT(20)
    DECLARE parent INT(20)
    DECLARE suparent INT(20)
    SELECT ref,ref_pa,ref_supa INTO ref,parent,suparent FROM users WHERE tid = OLD.tid;
        IF(ref != 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO earnings (`tid`,`amount`,`type`,`ref_tid`) VALUES           (ref,OLD.inv,'ref',OLD.tid);
    IF(parent != 0) THEN 
        INSERT INTO earnings (`tid`,`amount`,`type`,`ref_tid`) VALUES               (parent,OLD.inv,'ref_pa',OLD.tid);
    IF(suparent != 0) THEN 
        INSERT INTO earnings (`tid`,`amount`,`type`,`ref_tid`) VALUES                        (suparent,OLD.inv,'ref_supa',OLD.tid);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The statement looks alright to me, however i am greeted with the following

errors

Static analysis:

4 errors were found during analysis.

> Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 253)
>
> Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 372)
>
> Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 505)
>
> Unrecognized statement type. (near "END" at position 643)

SQL query: Documentation

```
CREATE NEW TRIGGER credit_refs AFTER UPDATE on investments FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DECLARE ref INT(20) DECLARE parent INT(20) DECLARE suparent INT(20) SELECT ref,ref_pa,ref_supa INTO ref,parent,suparent FROM users WHERE tid = OLD.tid; IF(ref != 0) THEN INSERT INTO earnings (`tid`,`amount`,`type`,`ref_tid`) VALUES (ref,OLD.inv,'ref',OLD.tid); IF(parent != 0) THEN INSERT INTO earnings (`tid`,`amount`,`type`,`ref_tid`) VALUES (parent,OLD.inv,'ref_pa',OLD.tid); IF(suparent != 0) THEN INSERT INTO earnings (`tid`,`amount`,`type`,`ref_tid`) VALUES (suparent,OLD.inv,'ref_supa',OLD.tid); END
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NEW TRIGGER credit_refs AFTER UPDATE on investments FOR EACH ROW**

```
 BEGIN
        DECL' at line 1
```

Hopefully someone here will be able to show me what im doing wrong here.

Comment: i am not too familiar with mysql - but don't you need to name your declared variables with @ at the beginning?

Comment: I have triggers defined that were written in the same standard, so no.

Comment: @EstebanP. that's ms sql syntax, not MySQL. In MySQL variables starting with @ are session variables and have completely different scope and role than variables defined within a trigger or any other stored routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER credit_refs AFTER UPDATE ON investments
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE ref INT(20);
    DECLARE parent INT(20);
    DECLARE suparent INT(20);
    SELECT ref,ref_pa,ref_supa INTO ref,parent,suparent FROM users WHERE tid = OLD.tid;
        IF(ref != 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO earnings (`tid`,`amount`,`type`,`ref_tid`) VALUES           (ref,OLD.inv,'ref',OLD.tid);
        END IF;
    IF(parent != 0) THEN 
        INSERT INTO earnings (`tid`,`amount`,`type`,`ref_tid`) VALUES               (parent,OLD.inv,'ref_pa',OLD.tid);
        END IF;
    IF(suparent != 0) THEN 
        INSERT INTO earnings (`tid`,`amount`,`type`,`ref_tid`) VALUES                        (suparent,OLD.inv,'ref_supa',OLD.tid);
        END IF;
END;
 $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Try above query.

In MySQL every **`IF`** statement must have **`END IF`**.You missed **`END IF`** for multiple if statement.

Comment: "In MySQL every IF statement must have END IF" that's not true `SELECT IF(1=1, 1, 0)`  is a valid MySQL query ...But the IF function i've described is a different IF statement.. The IF statement the topic started used needs indeed a `END IF`

Comment: How would i go about adding an IF statement after Begin? I only need the query to run if the updated field's value is 1, i tried adding it myself but i ran into syntax errors.

Comment: @SagarGangwal if you could bear with me for a moment, i altered the statement and added another IF after declaring the variables but i run into errors. Here's the statement, can you take a look?https://notey.it/n/MTJxeg

Comment: @HaiderAli just remove `==` to `=` only single `=` is needed.    `BEGIN
    DECLARE reff INT(20);
    DECLARE parent INT(20);
    DECLARE suparent INT(20);
        IF(NEW.confirmed = 1) THEN`

Comment: @RaymondNijland do not mix up the if() function with the if statement! All if statements in MySQL must have a corresponding end if.

Answer (score 1):

The warnings around the IFs are just phpmyadmin's own check. The syntax error you get is caused by the `NEW` keyword, which is not needed. As per [MySQL manual on creating triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html):

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    TRIGGER trigger_name
    trigger_time trigger_event
    ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
    [trigger_order]
    trigger_body
```

However, your IFs are not closed by `END IF`, and you are also missing semicolons at the end of the `declare` statements.

Comment: Do you mean the OLD keyword. cos im not using the NEW keyword, and without the OLD keyword how would i access the value from the investments table?

Comment: i'm so sorry, i see what you mean now.